# redirect after image uploaded with imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, gd

I'm currently trying to use the GD library to crop and upload an image. I upload the image first to the server and save the url to the image which I then pass to the following script which reads the original uploaded image and it crops it according to the coordinate that I give it.

```
<?php

   $w = $h = 150;
   $quality = 90;

   $src = $_POST['path'];
   $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
   $kak = ImageCreateTrueColor( $w, $h );
   imagecopyresampled($kak,$img,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
   $w,$h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   imagejpeg($kak,'c.jpg',$quality);
   imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

All works fine, image upload, crop and cropped image upload. The problem is that this page is completely empty and I would like to redirect the visitor to a different page but if I add

```
header ("Location: nextpage.php");
```

at the end of my php script it obviously redirects before finishing uploading. Does anyone know how to do this once the file has been uploaded successfully?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot really believe that. Btw, the `Content-Type` header isn't required. (and `image/jpeg` isn't the mime-type of a php page)

Comment: Remove first header().

Also, sending 'path' with $_POST is not safe...

Comment: Thanks both. It works perfectly. Now I'll need to figure out how to pass the path in a secure way. Cheers